# Using ZXing to analyze camera preview on Android

Tags: android, maui, zxing, zxing.net

I want to write a maui app where I use the ZXing `BarcodeReaderGeneric` to analyzer the camera preview from the `Camera2` of my android phone.

Assuming the camera is already running, I am using the `Android.Media.ImageReader` to get notified when a new image is available from the camera.

```
m_ImageReader = ImageReader.NewInstance(camera.Width, camera.Height, ImageFormatType.Yuv420888, 2);
m_ImageReader.SetOnImageAvailableListener
```

When an image is available, I want to use the barcode reader to decode a barcode on that image as fast as possible.

At first, I tried to analyze only the first plane of the image by using an `RGBLuminanceSource` to analyze the whole image, which worked but turned out to be very slow.

Then I read an `PlanarYUVLuminanceSource` would be the better options for the camera image. So I took all three planes of the image and put them in a single buffer, like

```
ByteBuffer yBuffer = image.GetPlanes()[0].Buffer;
ByteBuffer uBuffer = image.GetPlanes()[1].Buffer;
ByteBuffer vBuffer = image.GetPlanes()[2].Buffer;

int yCount = yBuffer.Remaining();
int uCount = uBuffer.Remaining();
int vCount = vBuffer.Remaining();

byte[] yBytes = new byte[yCount];
byte[] uBytes = new byte[uCount];
byte[] vBytes = new byte[vCount];

yBuffer.Get(yBytes, 0, yCount);
uBuffer.Get(uBytes, 0, uCount);
vBuffer.Get(vBytes, 0, vCount);

byte[] allBytes = new byte[yCount + uCount + vCount];

System.Buffer.BlockCopy(yBytes, 0, allBytes, 0, yCount);
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(uBytes, 0, allBytes, yCount, uCount);
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(vBytes, 0, allBytes, yCount + uCount, vCount);
```

but when I use the `PlanarYUVLuminanceSource` like

```
var source = new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(allBytes, image.Width, image.Height, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, false);
var result = m_BarcodeReader.Decode(source);
```

the barcode is never found and result is always null. I don't know why.

After this I wanted to try the cropping feature of the `PlanarYUVLuminanceSource` to not have to decode the whole image, but even the decoding of the whole image is not working.
Maybe one more idea is to make a 640x480 image from the camera image, but I don't have a clue how to do that.

So can anyone tell me what the best practice workflow is in such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at newer barcode libraries like https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning. ZXing was designed to use the old camera API, which produces YUV data in a different format than the newer camera2 API does.

If you do want to use ZXing, you'll need to translate `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888` into `ImageFormat.NV21`. Mainly, this means handling the row stride correctly.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. It also seems to be a lot faster.